# GooGooStatementCache - Multiply prepared statement!

Tags: java, hibernate, demoiselle, persistência

Ola, ao alterar um objeto e salvar estou com problemas de lentidão e em alguns momentos até trava totalmente minha aplicação.
Ao persistir está me retornando apenas essa informação, mas não consegui identificar o que pode ser.

> stmt.GooGooStatementCache - Multiply prepared statement! select
>   itemgrupo0_.id as id1_92_0_, itemgrupo0_.nome as nome2_92_0_,
>   itemgrupo0_.observacao as observac3_92_0_, itemgrupo0_.parent_id as
>   parent_i6_92_0_, itemgrupo0_.situacao as situacao4_92_0_,
>   itemgrupo0_.last_update as last_upd5_92_0_ from item_grupo itemgrupo0_
>   where itemgrupo0_.id=?

Essa informação pode indicar alguma coisa que estou fazendo e está errada?
Isso pode estar causando a lentidão no meu processo para salvar?

Código que ocasiona o erro:

```
@Transactional
@RequiredPermission(resource = Resources.NOTA_ENTRADA, operation = Operations.UPDATE)
public String updateCreditos() {
    try {
        if (this.getBean().getItens() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        for (NotaFiscalItem it : this.getBean().getItens()) {
            if (it.getId() != null && it.getId() < 0) {
                it.setId(null);
            }
            if (!this.getItemH().zeraValores(it)) {
                return "./entrada_itens.jsf";
            }
            if (it.getId() == null) {
                this.notaItemBC.insert(it);
            } else {
                this.notaItemBC.update(it);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        CriareLog.log(e);
        this.getMessageContext().add(e.getMessage(), SeverityType.ERROR);
        this.notaItemBC.rollback();
        return null;
    }
    this.endConversation();
    return this.getPreviousView();
}

@Override
@Transactional
public T update(T entity) {
    return getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}
```

Comment: Está usando c3p0? Coloca o código Java que está ocasionando o problema.

Comment: Usamos sim, acabei de editar a questão colocando o código on de salva.

Comment: Voce achou solucao pra isso? Obrigado.

Comment: Eu acredito que achei sim, mas não vou saber lhe dizer qual foi. Desculpe! @GuilhermeMussi